# Using branched svn repository in Eclipse without Subversive/Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, subversive

How can I use a new branch in Eclipse if I'm not using Subversive or Subclipse?  Do I have to checkout the new branch and import that as a new project into Eclipse?  Is there an easier way to do it, or is using Subversive or Subclipse the only reasonable way?

I know there are many discussions on the pros/cons of Subversive or Subclipse - I'm not asking which one would be best (although I will probably go with Subclipse if needed), and I'm not able to switch to a DVCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have imported the projects without copying them into the workspace, you can just do a `svn switch` and refresh the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to checkout the new branch and import the resulting code into Eclipse.